# Looping and sum the array values in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this:

```
array(5) {
         ["Uniform"]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
        array(2) {
          ["invoice_pname"]=>
          string(7) "Uniform"
          ["amount"]=>
          string(3) "900"
        }
        [1]=>
        array(2) {
          ["invoice_pname"]=>
          string(7) "Uniform"
          ["amount"]=>
          string(3) "450"
        }
      }

      ["Tuition Fee"]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
        array(2) {
          ["invoice_pname"]=>
          string(11) "Tuition Fee"
          ["amount"]=>
          string(3) "300"
        }
        [1]=>
        array(2) {
          ["invoice_pname"]=>
          string(11) "Tuition Fee"
          ["amount"]=>
          string(3) "300"
        }
      }
    }
```

I want to add the array values inside the key elements, like:

Uniform => 1350

Tuition Fee => 600

What I do is I use `foreach` as the loop,

```
 $results = array();
 foreach ($result as $key => $resultant) {
    foreach ($resultant as $value) {
          $results[$key][] += $value['amount'];  
     }
  }

  var_dump($results);
```

but it's showing an error

```
<h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>
<p>Severity: Notice</p>
<p>Message:  Undefined index: Uniform</p>
<p>Filename: controllers/Home.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 2787</p>
<p>Backtrace:</p>
```

Can anybody help me? I want to show it in a table.

Answer (score 0):

Looking to your data you should iterate over  result['Uniform']

```
$results = array();
  foreach ($result['Uniform'] as $key => $resultant) {
     foreach ($resultant as $value) {
        $results[$key][] += $value['amount'];  
     }
  }
```

because seem is this this key the one that contain the valid array for sum

Answer (score 0):

You can use [array_column](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) and [array_sum](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php).
That way you don't need to loop the full array.

```
Foreach($arr as $key => $a){
    $res[$key] = array_sum(array_column($a, "amount"));
}
Var_dump($res);
```

https://3v4l.org/Wba3Q